# performSelectorAfterDelay unreliable on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I have a stopwatch class that updates the view periodically in its `tick` method. The method gets triggered via

```
[self performSelector:@selector(tick) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1f];
```

This works fine on the iPhone where the view gets updated approx. every tenth of a second.

Now I want to use the same class to achieve this on the Apple Watch. When I start the stopwatch the view gets updated kind of OK. However after 2 seconds the framerate drops and the stopwatch becomes unusable.

Here is the whole `tick` method:

```
- (void)tick {
if (!self.running) return;
NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval elapsed = currentTime - startTime;
if (countdown) {
    curTime = originalTime - (elapsed * 1000);
}else {
    curTime = originalTime + (elapsed * 1000);
    curTime -= offset;
}

[self.delegate stopwatch:self tick:curTime];
long thisThousand = curTime / 1000;

if (curTime > 0 || !countdown) {
    if (thisThousand != lastThousand) {
        long seconds = curTime / 1000;
        if (countdown) seconds++;
        [self.delegate stopwatch:self fullSecond:seconds];
    }
    lastThousand = curTime / 1000;
    [self performSelector:@selector(tick) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1f];
} else {
    curTime = 0;
    [self.delegate stopwatch:self fullSecond:0];
    [self.delegate stopwatchStoped:self];
    [self stopTimer];
}
}
```

Any ideas on how to get that to work. Or an alternative solution?

Many thanks!

**EDIT**:
The UI is just a simple label and not a fancy animation. The label should just be set from 0:00:00.1 to 0:00:00.2 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

If you're updating views from this method (I'm assuming `[self.delegate stopwatch:self fullSecond:seconds]` updates a view?) If YES then you ought to look at CoreAnimation. Animations are much better designed to handle view changes over time (after all that's what an animation is!). If you're animating a second hand you could create an animation that makes it "tick" and simply repeat the process indefinitely. There are also delegate methods that inform you when an animation has completed that you can use to do any other calculations.

[Look here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for docs on CoreAnimation.

An alternative to `performSelector:afterDelay:` would be to use `NSTimer`:

```
// timer is an iVar
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// then to stop the timer
[timer invalidate];
```

I would suggest CoreAnimation first.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Core Animation isn't available in WatchKit, currently.

Comment: Ahh. That's annoying. Hopefully it will be soon and then you can all upvote this excellent answer.